# How to create PDF using soft line break so that can be copy and paste in iText7?

Tags: pdf, itext7

I create PDF using iText7, both in English and Chinese. But when other people want to copy and paste the content of PDF to Word or other text editor, there is a forced line break at the end of every line, and the spaces in front of every paragraph are lost.

Is there a way to get over this, so that I can copy the paragraph as continuous text and keep the spaces in front of every paragraph?

I tried to search on internet and it seems an very old question (like: [Copy from PDF without line breaks at end of each line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91567/copy-from-pdf-without-line-breaks-at-end-of-each-line)) but I could not find good solutions. Does anyone know any progress on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a simple document, the job of `iText7` in simplest terms is to split your long text into lines and write those lines into a PDF document. It is the job of your viewer/reader to extract text correctly.

However, this is a very much non-trivial job. For the simplest example, imagine one case of a sentence which is long enough for one line and this occupies two lines, and another case when there is an explicit line break (`\n`) in the middle of text. In both cases, the visual representation would be two lines of glyphs, and it is very hard if not impossible to distinguish between these two cases and restore original logical text correctly.

But there is a notion of tagged PDF, i.e. PDF with some meta information about content that you put in your PDF file, such as hierarchy of tables, paragraphs etc in your document. This tagging information may very well help to distinguish between those two cases mentioned above. It depends on the viewer whether it will respect the tagging information, but many viewers do. Tagging the document might facilitate text extraction in your case.

To create a tagged document in `iText7`, use `pdfDocument.setTagged()` method, but make sure to call it *before* you add any content to it. Ideally call this method right after the constructor.